# using an inherited/extended concrete class name in a toString()

Tags: java, class, oop, tostring

Hi everyone at the moment, my toString() looks like this:

```
public String toString () 
    {
        return ("A " + size + "cm " + weight +  "kg Fish" );
    }
```

which prints out something like this: "A 16cm 0.2kg Fish"

I am looking for it print out something like this: "A 16cm 0.2kg Bass", where Bass inherits its attributes from a `NonEndangeredFish` class which inhertis its attributes from a `Fish` class. The to String is currently located in the `Fish` class. This is the `Fish` class:

```
public abstract class Fish 
{
    // Any fish below this size must be thrown back into the lake
    public static int  THROW_BACK_SIZE = 18; 
    public static float WEIGHT_LIMIT = 10;

    protected float weight;
    protected int  size;


    public Fish(int aSize, float aWeight) 
    {
        size = aSize;
        weight = aWeight;
    }


    public boolean isDesirableTo(Fisher f) 
    {
        if(canKeep() && f.numFishCaught < f.LIMIT && this.weight + f.sumOfWeight < WEIGHT_LIMIT)
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean canKeep(); 

    public int getSize() { return size; }
    public float getWeight() { return weight; }

    public String toString () 
    {
        return ("A " + size + "cm " + weight +  "kg" );
    }
```

this is the superclass. An EndangeredFish class and a  NonEndangeredFish class extends the Fish class (which are both abstract). Then a Perch class and Bass class extend the NonEndangeredFish class and the AtlanticWhiteFish class and the AuroraTrout class extends the Endangered class. my question is how would I use a class name in a toString()? I tried declaring a string in the Perch, AuroraTrout, AtlanticWhiteFish and Bass called name and using it in the toString and it did not work, then I tried declaring a name (a String) in the fish class and then making a constructor with three parameters but that didnt work so Im really stuck. This is how a fish is added:

```
public class FishingTestProgram2 
{

    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        // Create a big lake with 15 fish
        Lake   weirdLake = new Lake(15);
        weirdLake.add(new AuroraTrout(76, 6.1f));
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(32, 0.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(20, 0.9f));
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(30, 0.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new AtlanticWhiteFish(140, 7.4f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(15, 0.3f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(90, 5.9f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(120, 6.8f));
        weirdLake.add(new AtlanticWhiteFish(80, 4.8f));
        weirdLake.add(new AuroraTrout(42, 3.2f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(100, 5.6f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(45, 2.0f));
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(16, 0.2f));
        weirdLake.add(new Bass(30, 1.2f));
        weirdLake.add(new Perch(7, 0.1f));
```

Any help is appreciated Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like this:

```
public String toString () 
{
    return ("A " + size + "cm " + weight +  " " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() );
}
```

Comment: would I put the getSimpleName() method inside the both the Endangered and the NonEndangered subclasses?

Comment: nope, in `Fish` only, that's the great thing about inheritance (not being sarcastic here, i mean it)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that they were supposed to overwrite `toString()` in every concrete class (I'm **not** saying that it's better):

```
class Bass {

   ...
   public String toString() {
      return super.toString() + " Bass"; 
   }

   ...

}
```